# How to add extra data in php foreach loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework and pasing array of arrays $products to view. In view I want to create tabs for products. Here is the code for view:

```
<ul class="tab">
    <?php foreach ($products as $products_item): ?>
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, '<?= $products_item['product_id']; ?>')"><?=$products_item['product_id']?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <?php foreach ($products as $products_item): ?>
        <div id="<?=$products_item['product_id']?>" class="tabcontent">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/uploads/<?php echo $products_item['image_url'];?>" /><br>   
            <?php echo $products_item['manufacturer']; ?><br>
            <?php echo $products_item['health']; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openProduct(evt, productId) {
        // Declare all variables
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

        // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }

        // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
        document.getElementById(productId).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
    </script>
```

It works well but there is no default tab. To add default tab I need to add

```
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

to my JS and `id="defaultOpen"` to first link. I have spent some hours on this and can not get my head around...

Comment: Well It depends on what your click function does to the tab. If it sets it to the active class and sets it's content to `display: block;`, for example, you'll have to add it in the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

- Find out no. of $products
- Use if to identify the 1st of $products to make it as the default tab.

Comment: Sorry but I did not get it. I tried to reread your answer but still do not get it. Could you please give a example or explain in more details?

Comment: if (i == 0) { tabcontent[0].style.display = "inline"; }else { tabcontent[i].style.display = "none"; }